# Android - Appium's mocked location will be overwritten by Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and mobile networks

Tags: android, mocking, location, appium

Within my Appium tests for an Android app I am using Appium's setLocation() of AndroidDriver to mock a location. This works properly, but since the app is requiring "High Accuracy" as location method the mocked location will be overwritten after a few seconds by the location which is generated by Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and mobile networks.

Is there any solution or workaround for this kind of issue? I want to set the location permantly (for the whole duration of the test), but can't change that the app is forcing the user to enable "High accuracy" mode.

Btw: I'm testing on a lot of different real devices and not on emulators.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. `setLocation` works, but is often overwritten by the real device's actual location.

Answer (score 1):

First enable developer option in your phone.

Go to your phone **Settings > About > Tap Rapidly on Build Number** until it says “You are now a developer.”

Then go into your **Developer Setting** and check **Allow mock locations**.

Now you need to **Download App** that will allow you to fake the GPS location. There are several different apps that can do this. You can find free app in play store.

Finally you can select a random spot somewhere in the world and activate the fake location using the app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't solve my issue. I need to mock several locations during the Appium tests, so doing it manually with external apps is not an option. I use Appium's build-in method setLocation() for mocking and it works, but it gets overwritten after a few seconds by the real location of the device (I think because of "High Accuary" mode on the device).

Comment: I'm still having this issue and really appriciate any suggestions.